# Travelling in India in the second half of July. Can I be affected by the monsoon?

Tags: india, transportation, weather-and-climate

I was considering travelling to India in the second half of July. I read that the monsoons finished around the 15th.
Is this so rigorous or is it just an average?

How is travelling in India after the monsoons? I assume with the heavy rain everything can be  affected, specially transports, which are vital for someone travelling.

Is everything regularized after or are can there be issues related with monsoons? (inaccessible places, delayed transport services, etc)

Comment: Bizarre. I was just wondering this myself 2 minutes ago, absentmindedly opened up travel.SE, and saw this on the front page.

Comment: According to the "Climate in India" wiki, the rainy season is from June to September, and "monsoon rains begin to recede from North India at the beginning of October", possibly later in the south.

Comment: Monsoon not the best time to travel if going by bus or train. Can get cancelled without notice when tracks/roads get submerged. If travelling in eastern India train cancellations are more or less sure in monsoon. Monsoons extend till Septemeber and sometimes till October too, July is just the start and not finished yet.

Comment: Apply the 3A's rue :-): "Never travel in Asia between April and August". Yes, that's joke BUT also a handy starting point to remember.

Answer (score 2):

Monsoon would be on the full swing in last week of July. Amount of rain will differ depending upon which part of the country you are in.India is a huge country. Rajasthan for example in some parts wont see any rain atall and may be a few drops if they get lucky this year. Nothing stops in India and as long as you stay away from the flood prone areas of eastern UP and Bihar you will be fine. Rains also mean that temperatures will come down. [Kerala](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/kerala-in-july.218/) gets plenty of rain in July and it remains hot and humid throughout but again nothing really stops.Traveling in the hills gets a bit tough and some land slides are not uncommon so if you are planning to go to places like [Manali](http://www.indiatravelforum.in/threads/traveling-to-manali-during-july.297/) or Leh by road then it is best avoided or just take a flight to Leh and skip Manali.

As you can imagine India gets monsoon every year so the infrastructure is built keeping that in mind and the disruption to traffic is minor. There may be slight delays because while it rains the traffic slows down a little to avoid slipping and may be a few traffic bottlenecks here and there so keep a 10-20% extra margin for traveling time.

I would also like to add that during monsoon it does not rain non stop. Rains may go on for 6-7 hours and then no rain for two days to give you an example.

Source : I live in India (New Delhi)

Comment: `Rains may go on for 6-7 hours` You sure, I have experienced rain going on continuously for 6-7 days or more with little breaks. Maybe in Delhi but not in the east and south.

Comment: India is a huge country. I saw rains for 10 days back in the 90s once in Delhi and it can happen again but normally it does not go on that long without dry spells in between. Depends which areas one wants to go.

Comment: About Manali: are you sure? Because the bike tours are usually held from June - Sept, and I'm planning to do so too with a local.

Comment: It occasionally rains continually in New Zealand for several days at a time. So ... :-)

Comment: @AyeshK  Bike tours are for adventure and that is what you are probably looking for. If you wanted comfort over some adventure then you would be driving a 4X4 or taking a volvo bus I guess. Rains do cause problems in the hills every year. Traffic jams and delays due to land slides are not that uncommon. I personally do go to the Himalayas once it starts raining. It is a matter of personal choice and preference.